# Page Builder use Child in the di.xml

Tags: magento2, di, page-builder, child

If we want to add a chiid in page builder like slider how will we inject the child using di.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add the child in the Pagebuilder in the di.xml :

```
<type name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\ContentType\AdditionalData\Provider\Wysiwyg\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="editors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/tinymce4Adapter" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/wysiwyg/tinymce4</item>
                <item name="component_initializers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="text" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/text/wysiwyg/tinymce4/component-initializer</item>
                    <item name="slide" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/slide/wysiwyg/tinymce4/component-initializer</item>
                    <item name="banner" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/banner/wysiwyg/tinymce4/component-initializer</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config_modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="text" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/text/wysiwyg/tinymce4/config-modifier</item>
                    <item name="slide" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/slide/wysiwyg/tinymce4/config-modifier</item>
                </item>
                <item name="mode" xsi:type="string">inline</item>
                <item name="minToolbarWidth" xsi:type="number">360</item>
                <item name="parentSelectorsToUnderlay" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">.column-container</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="string">.row-container</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```